# Odd multiplicities cut the x axis, Even multiplicity rebound, Why ??

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, roots, quadratics

I can understand why it happens in simple cases like x^2 and x^3

In x^2 whether the x values are +ve or -ve the the function will always give a +ve value because g gets squared
Root 0 with multiplicity 2 only touches thr graph

In x^3, when x values are +ve the function will give +ve values and when the x values are -ve the function will give -ve values
Cause cubes of +ve are +ve and cubes of -ve are negative
Therefore the root 0 with multiplicity 3 cut through the graph

But I don’t understand why that happens in more completed cases where there are at least 2 distinct roots

Like

(X - 1)(X-1)(X-3)

(X + 2)(X-3)(X -3)(X-3)

Could someone please explain why even and odd multiplicities act the way they do in the 2 examples given above

Comment: Found an answer I was able to comprehend in a khan academy video

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/x2ec2f6f830c9fb89:poly-graphs/x2ec2f6f830c9fb89:poly-intervals/a/zeros-of-polynomials-and-their-graphs  Answer at 5:20

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $r$ is a root of polynomial $p(x)$. Then you can factor
$$
p(x) = (x-r)^mq(x)
$$
where $m$ is the multiplicity of the root and $q(r) \ne 0$. The polynomial $q(x)$ has all the other roots of $p(x)$ but we don't care what they are.

Then when $x$ is near $r$ you know $q(x) \ne 0$ and has the same sign.

If $m$ is even then $(x-r)^m$ is positive on both sides of $r$ so the graph does not cross the $x$-axis there. If $m$ is odd then $(x-r)^m$ changes sign and the graph crosses the axis. (In either case the $x$ axis is a tangent - even when it crosses the graph.)

Comment: In the last para you only consider (x-r)^m to have an affect on sign change of p(x), and don’t consider q(x). Why are you able to do that ?

Comment: Because $q(r) \ne 0$, it has the same sign on both sides of $r$ (in a small enough neighborhood of $r$). Thus it does not affect whether the graph touches or crosses the $x$-axis.